# KafkaJS consume from multiple topics with one consumer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I want to implement `retry` logic while consuming from `Kafka topic` using [KafkaJS](https://kafka.js.org/), so basically, I will have 2 topics `main-topic` and `retry-topic` and I will

read from -> `main-topic`
if processing fails | -> `retry topic`

so is it a bad practice to use one `consumer` for listening from both topics(both `main` and `retry`), as `kafka` allows to listen from multiple topics using same consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad practice at all.

The only problem you may run into using one consumer is that the topics may need differ configurations (connection settings, deserializer, etc). In that case, you can create two separate Consumer instances rather than one subscribing to both.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, suppose I have 3-4 sets of `topics` (main and retry) and I'm using `nodejs` single thread. Won't it affect the event loop if I have 6-8 different `kafka consumer instance` ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Polling is a blocking operation, so the thread would alternate between the two (or more). You could also look at the child_process module for spawning multiple OS node processes